# Check URL any time URL change in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to change the display of elements. I use jQuery and my problem is that it only checks URL in the begging and in the next change of URL it is not working.

```
    <script>
        alert(window.location.href);
    
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("drinks=spirits") > -1) {
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    
    }
    
    </script>
```

For example:
I follow this order:

1- On the first visit, the URL is `HTTP://example.com/drinks=spirits` and it works.

2- Then I click on a filter, since I use ajax without reloading the page the URL changes to `HTTP://example.com/drinks=spirits&price=less_10`.

3- Then again when I remove the filter (again the page is not reloaded, it only removes the query) and the URL will be `HTTP://example.com/drinks=spirits`. **Now the `alert` does not appear!**

I am looking for a solution that shows the `alert` anytime users redirects to the `HTTP://example.com/drinks=spirits`

Answer (score 1):

You need the `hashchange` event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
  alert(window.location.href);

  if (window.location.href.indexOf("drinks=spirits") > -1) {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it is not working for me. I try : `window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
  alert(window.location.href);
});` but it doesn't alert anything.